# Application download from App store

Tags: android, ios, android-layout, app-store

I was trying to find out what exactly happens when you download an application from App store.
 What we see is the application icon present on the phone GUI interface.

To be more accurate like a few doubts I have are

1) How does the icon appear on the screen.
  2) How the icon is linked to the application executable.

I really dont know whether the question is simple or tough. Even a pointer to some documentation can be helpful to me.

Comment: The icon is specified in the manifest and supplied in the Drawable folders, that is how its all linked.

Comment: The launcher displays the icon.  You could write a launcher that, for example, only displays the name of the app.  It's not an Android function.  The launcher gets the icon by querying the package manager.  Most launchers then cache the icon for faster restarts after a boot.